# how to scale collection view cells height to the size of screen in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, scale

I have a collection view that the height of the cells won't change when I will run the application in bigger screen iPhone I used this code But when I will run this code I can't see my collection view in my app

**remember that I have horizontal collection view that contains one line**

```
var cellWidth:CGFloat = 0
var cellHeight:CGFloat = 0
var spacing:CGFloat = 12
var numberOfColumn:CGFloat = 9


//Scale Collection View
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    specialCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)

    if let flowLayout = specialCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        cellHeight = view.frame.size.height / specialCollectionView.frame.height
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
    }
}
```

and here is the extension code

```
extension secondTabViewController:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
      }
}
```

Comment: try calling viewDidLayoutSubviews() operation in viewDidAppera instead of viewDidLayoutSubviews and check if that works.

Comment: I used that and still I can't see the collection view - look I can see collectionView when I comment this code